# What is the brightest, biggest & baddest white LED to date?

Tags: led

I'm looking to make a DIY LED projector with a single LED (even if its a very small projector, might make an array of projectors with edge-blending, don't have the specifics yet, but it has to be energy efficient) and I was wondering who makes such a LED or if there is experimental technology in the works to make brighter LEDs.

Comment: This sort of question has a moving target, and is thus discouraged on SE. That said, your best bet is looking at the press releases for leading LED companies such as Cree, Luxeon, Lumileds, etc. You will probably find that a DIY LED projector will be an expensive and/or dim proposition at the present time.

Comment: The answers to this question will soon be out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luminius devices SST-90 is a 9mm^2 beast of an LED that can chuck out a massive 2000+ lumens. - http://www.luminus.com/products/SST-90.html
The CREE XM-L is also a nice device if you want something smaller.

Note that for a projector you want to produce the light in the smallest possible area and as such - those big "panel" like LED's are no good to you.

There is an epic thread that you no doubt would have come across while searching about DIY'ing a LED projector - http://lumenlab.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=24619
Has heaps of good info in there ;)

Answer (score 2):

Big 5 + a few more make LEDs around 5 Watt. These are now getting 130 + l/W at less than full power and down to 100-120 l/W at full power or about 500 lumen.

These may not be single die so you have to determine whether they are point source enough for you.

A recent Nichia is NSCWL060 with 300 mA absolute maximum continuous at 33 Volt.
 33v x 0.3A = 9.9 Watt.
 670 lumen at 160 mA.
 I'd guesstimate 1000 - 1100 lumen at full full power. 
Given that "2000 ANSI lumen" was  a good projector spec a few years ago, this may do OK even allowing for losses in the internal light path.

12 die in series internally. 
Whether that can be focused well enough using a magic lens is tbd.

Colour at about 0.34,0.36 on CIE1931 luminance chart. (That's probably about 5600K I think)
About 4 c/w thermal resistance.

Cree, Lumileds, Osram, Nichia, Avago, Seoul Semiconductor, more ...
Be very careful re non-name brands especially in this sort of high power role. Even eg "Cree inside" is not enough certainty as die packaging has its own issues.